# node.js dynamic chat room

Tags: node.js, socket.io, chat

I am relatively new to using node.js and I have been searching for awhile but I haven't been successful in implementing socket.join

I have a chat room which I want to be setup privately between two users, similar to private messaging.

What I wish to have is make dynamic chat rooms between users. The problem I am getting right now is that the messages are still being broadcast to all the clients connected to the server.

Here's what I have on the server

server.js

```
io.sockets.on( 'connection', function( socket ) {

    var unique_room = "";

    socket.on('join', function(room) {
        socket.join(room);
        unique_room = room;
        console.log("User Joined the room: "+room);
    });

    socket.on('message', function (data) {
        io.sockets.in(unique_room).emit('message', data.message);
    });

});

server.listen(1337);
```

client.js

```
var socket = io.connect( 'http://localhost:1337' );

socket.on('connect', function() {
     socket.emit('join', 'dddsdjkfh1123'); //chat room id unique to two users
});

socket.on( 'message', function( data ) {
     $("#chat" ).html(data.user + ":" + data.message);
});

//Form js
function sendpm(room,message,name) { 
     socket.emit( 'message', { room: room, message: message, name: name });
}
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should emit some the room id from the client when you send the message, and get that room id to send message to only that client in that room.

Try doing this in your server.js:

```
io.sockets.on( 'connection', function( socket ) {

socket.on('join', function(room) {
    socket.join(room);
    socket.room = room;
    console.log("User Joined the room: "+socket.room);
});

socket.on('message', function (data) {
    io.sockets.in(data.room).emit('message', data.message);
});

});
```